# Solving a kinky secondary order ODE via Python Scipy

Tags: python, math, scipy, numerical-methods, ode

I have the following second order ODE and I wish to solve it via Python Scipy:

[image: ODE]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: So if the solution is not constant, you have `y'' = - sign(y') - sin(y)`?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, that is correct.

Comment: In this version the solver will stall out at some point, the time not advancing. It is better to soften the sign function like `y'/(eps+abs(y'))` or `tanh(y'/eps)` with some moderately small value for `eps`. // In the original equation, it is admissible to switch to a constant segment whenever `y'=0`, and resume the non-constant version after some random time. One could use the event mechanism to detect points where such a branching is possible. There is no automatic mechanism that produces branching, the solver is deterministic.

Comment: As it stands you could integrate it once: d/dx[-cos(y)+(1/2)y'^2+sy]=0, where s is the sign of dy/dx. Then dy/dx=s.sqrt(2(C-sy+cos(y))), where C is piecewise constant. So at least you only have a first-order ODE to deal with and you could detect when C-sy+cos(y)=0